# What amount of hashrate can we estimate Google's 53 qubit Sycamore quantum computer could yield?

Tags: quantum-computing

Could Sycamore be programmed to perform massively parallel SHA256 searching?

If so, how much hashrate do you estimate this 53 qubit machine could yield?

Is there enough public information to be able to estimate this or do other factors such as the computer's memory and QPU architecture come into play?

Comment: Related https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10942/5406